# How to change position of map buttons using vuetify in mobile view

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How can I change the position of my default Google map buttons on changing from desktop view to mobile view using only vuetify?

I tried using some breakpoints but as these are the default button, they are not in any v-flex so I am not able to get it done.

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far? Please give more context/code for us to try to help you.

Comment: You can use a `@media` CSS query for these buttons.